# Select records more recent than one of two date/times in SQL and ESRI definition query

Tags: sql, sql-server, esri

I am an ESRI SQL user- so my query **has** to start with: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE`:

I have GPS-based vehicle records (snowplows) with a date/time field (called timedate) and I need to either A.) select records that have occurred in the previous x number of hours based on an integer field in a separate table or B.) select records that are newer than a date/time based on a date/time field in a separate table.  If it is case A, then the field in case B will be null.  If it is case B, then the field in case A will be 0.

Here's what I've written for case A.

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable
WHERE(DATEDIFF(hh, TimeDate, GETDATE()) <= (select NumberofHours from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
AND Fleet = 'District 2'
AND NOT [Speed] = 0
AND ([AssetDesc] LIKE  'Sander/Plow%' AND Input2On = 'On' AND Input1On = 'On'))
```

And here's what I've written for case B.

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable
WHERE(TimeDate <= (select StartTime from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
AND Fleet = 'District 2'
AND NOT [Speed] = 0
AND([AssetDesc] LIKE  'Sander/Plow%' AND Input2On = 'On' AND Input1On = 'On'))
```

They both work, but can someone help me put it together?  When I've tried with a case statement, I keep getting the error: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."  I also have the limitation of having to start with "Select *" since I'm doing this in an ESRI definition query.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can esri generate variables and send them to sql server as parameters?

Comment: I don't know.  I could test that.

Comment: After looking at it, I don't think so- unless I'm missing something you have to declare your variable outside of your WHERE clause, correct?  So, I can't do that because I'm stuck inside the WHERE clause.

Comment: @sernst How are you executing your code? I'm wondering what ESRI is...

Comment: @meewoK ESRI is GIS software (for making maps).  This is all spatial data- I can apply what they call a "definition query" but then I'm stuck within that WHERE clause.  I'm basically trying to limit the data shown on a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very quick thought. Probably not the most optimized but Why not simply coming and two WHERE statements using an OR?

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable
WHERE(
(
(DATEDIFF(hh, TimeDate, GETDATE()) <= (select NumberofHours from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
AND Fleet = 'District 2'
AND NOT [Speed] = 0
AND ([AssetDesc] LIKE  'Sander/Plow%' AND Input2On = 'On' AND Input1On = 'On')) 
)
OR
(
(TimeDate <= (select StartTime from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
AND Fleet = 'District 2'
AND NOT [Speed] = 0
AND([AssetDesc] LIKE  'Sander/Plow%' AND Input2On = 'On' AND Input1On = 'On')) 
)
```

### Update

Since both A) and B) share a large number of conditions, you could combine like below. This is taking for granted you want to catch rows fulfilling conditions EITHER A) OR B).

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable
WHERE
  (    
    DATEDIFF(hh, TimeDate, GETDATE()) <= 
    (select NumberofHours from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
  OR 
    TimeDate <= (select StartTime from myHoursControlTable where District = 2)
  )
AND Fleet = 'District 2'
AND NOT [Speed] = 0
AND ([AssetDesc] LIKE  'Sander/Plow%' AND Input2On = 'On' AND Input1On = 'On');
```

Comment: Your top solution worked.  I didn't think something that simple would work.  Thank you.  I like the Update better, but when I run it, it's ignoring the AND parameter- it returns all of the districts and not just District 2.

Comment: @sernst most likely something is going on with the brackets. I'm pretty sure the error is there...

Comment: @sernst Have a look at number 2 again, I cleaned up the brackets a bit and fixed a mistake.